# "loving" vs. "love"

Tags: meaning, punctuation

> Boy your loving is all I think about

1) Why not a comma after 'boy'? Is this grammar correct, because it looks like two subjects?

2) Why not 'love'?  What's the difference in this sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since "Boy" is direct address, one would normally separate it from the rest with a comma.

As for "loving" vs. "love" ... "loving" implies the physical act of love much more strongly than "love" alone would — so it's plain to see what the speaker is after.

Comment: "Boy" is also slightly ambiguous in this context due to the exclamation, "Boy!" as in: "Wow, your loving is all I think about!"